# What's the right practice of resourcePrefix?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

If I add

```
resourcePrefix "stool"
```

in build.gradle,it even warned me when I wrote

```
<declare-styleable name="FlexToolBar">

</declare-styleable>
```

It told me change FlexToolBar to stoolFlexToolBar.

Do I need to remove resourcePrefix or close the warn about it?

What's the real use of resourcePrefix?

Comment: Have you used the prefix in the xml definition, when you use the custom view right

Answer (score 1):

Best way to declare the prefix is just use the name of your custom view as prefix which is generally prefer.

you should use

```
tools:ignore="stool"
```

to ignore warnings.

resourcePrefix in XML definition. 
Namespaces uniquely identify code/libraries. XML namespace to find the XML attribute.

You can further refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace

```
xmlns:stool="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/stool"
<....
 stool:FlexToolBar_size=""
    ../>
```

If you add

```
resourcePrefix "stool"
```

Then you have to use the

In java code you have to use the

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.FlexToolBar, defStyle, 0);

 int index = a.getInt(R.styleable.FlexToolBar_size, -1);
```

Comment: I think resourcePrefix  is prefix of resource.

Comment: I should use tools:ignore="ResourceName" to ignore warnings.

Comment: yes firstly you need to add the xmlns:stool="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/stool" as well